# Deletion of 1 million records with BulkWrite (DeleteManyModel) taking longer time

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have collection of 5 million records and every time data refresh happens , i wanted to delete Approx. 1 Million records. I am using below java code but it taking 30 Sec to delete. that is to high for application response time. Please suggest me better approach to reduce query response time.

I have created compound index on fields which i am using in the `where` clause.

Created compound index on these field : `{“collection_id” : 1,“client_id” : 1,“version” : -1}`

```
package com.eka.db.mongo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.BulkWriteOptions;
import com.mongodb.client.model.DeleteManyModel;
import com.mongodb.client.model.WriteModel;

public class DeleteDocumentBulk {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("integ28");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<WriteModel<Document>> deleteManyModel = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject dataVersion = new JSONObject().put("$lt", 23);
        JSONObject jsonQuery = new JSONObject();
        jsonQuery.put("collection_id", "123321");
        jsonQuery.put("version", dataVersion);
        jsonQuery.put("client_id", "8");
        BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions = new BulkWriteOptions();
        bulkWriteOptions.ordered(false);
        bulkWriteOptions.bypassDocumentValidation(true);
        deleteManyModel.add(new DeleteManyModel<Document>(Document.parse(jsonQuery.toString())));
        database.getCollection("BulkInsertTesting").bulkWrite(deleteManyModel, bulkWriteOptions);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println("Document Deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check, whether your code is causing the slow deletion or is it the same if your executing a command directly on the database?

Comment: @juwil : Its taking 15 Sec , while executing directly on the database.  with this query :db.BulkInsertTesting.bulkWrite([
     { deleteMany : { "filter" : {client_id: "8" ,collection_id: "123321",  version: { $lt: 23 } } } }  
  ],{ ordered : false });      Is there any better approach, we can try to reduce time.

Comment: since even direct execution is too long for waiting for an response, you might consider an asyncronous execution of your java code (assuming, your code is just an example and you want to execute it in another aplication).  And to what value is maxWriteBatchSize for your database?

Comment: @juwil "maxWriteBatchSize" : 100000

Comment: so i would try to increase the batchsize to better match your bulk operation size and see, if this increases execution speed.